# Tor fails to launch in Windows 10 when I click on the icon

Tags: windows

Since an update about 3 months ago I have been unable to get Tor to launch when I click on the icon.   The process firefox.exe appears briefly but disappears after a second or two without actually launching the programme. I have tried downloading the latest version and with the experimental version, and have tried running from my hard drive and from USB.  Reading some similar queries I don't appear to have any issue with time settings and am not duel boot.  I will continue to read the answers to similar questions in case this throws more light on it.  Thanks in anticipation of your comments.

I have had a request to clarify my enquiry.  If you can tell me what details I need to give I will supply them as best I can.

Comment: Check for antivirus, firewall, "security" software like trusteer rapport, etc.